# How to remove empty div with any class by php

Tags: php

How to remove empty div with any class by php  .Here is the code.

```
<li>
<a class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav" href="https://twitter.com/EnglishBlogCom" data-user-id="376638112">
<small class="time">
<p class="TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--26px js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--reply"></div>
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--retweet js-toggleState js-toggleRt"> </div>
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--retweet js-toggleState js-toggleRt"> </div>
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--favorite js-toggleState withHeartIcon"> </div>
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--favorite js-toggleState withHeartIcon"> </div>
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--more js-more-ProfileTweet-actions">
<div class="dropdown"> </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown"> </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You don't remove `<div>`s with PHP. You do that with JavaScript.

Comment: explain or post the complete code what you tryed.. dealing with html elements are done with client side script.

Comment: I get this as post parametr i need remove empty div tags by regex

Answer (score 1):

try with this.. it check each element having class *.dropdown* and check whether it is empty.

**jQuery**

```
$('.dropdown').each(function(i, obj) {
    if( $(this).is(':empty') ) { 
          $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

div remove with jquery try this code

```
if($("div").empty()){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: op specifically asked about a php solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery` for that

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").each(function()
            {
            if($(this).empty())
                $(this).remove()
            });
         })
</script>
```